# Php regex for maths equation

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have a string that contain a math equation as follows

```
$eq = '(x^2) * (x^3) = x^5';
```

i need to replace `^` and change the value to php related function

```
$eq = 'pow(x, 2) * pow(x, 3) = pow(x, 5)';
```

i tried:

```
$eq = preg_replace('/(\d+)\w\^\w(\d+)/', "pow($1, $2)", '(x^2) * (x^3) = x^5');
```

but not working.

Comment: `/(\w+)\s*\^\s*(\w+)/`

Answer (score 0):

Your regex (\d+)\w\^\w(\d+) does not catch (x^2) because it needs to have a number before the x and something between the ^ and the \d+.

If you want to make some parameters optional, you can postfix them with a "?"

If all your elements are of the type (x^n) or x^n, this regex works:

```
$eq = preg_replace('/\(?(\w+)\^(\d+)\)?/', "pow($1, $2)", $eq);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$eq          = '(x^2) * (x^3) = x^5';
$replacement = 'pow($1,$2)';

print preg_replace('/\(?(x)\^(\d)\)?+/', $replacement, $eq);
```